# Will a pact with a Demon change the paper trail of the Demon and mortal?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Henry is a white collar criminal who got sent to jail for embezzlement at a bank. His life is ruined. I, as a demon, make a pact with Henry to take on that aspect of his life. Now I am a known embezzler, and Henry's record is clean and he can get a new job and a new life.

How far do the changes go? Certainly Henry's family and friends will be affected by the change. But will the prison records show that I was in prison? Will the court records show that I was convicted? What about the FBI records?

The reason I ask is that the pact is not worth much to the mortal if a casual check by an employer would break it. It also makes sense to me that electronic records are more amenable to such changes, while memories might not be.  That is, while nearby people might have their memories changed, people far away might still remember Henry as the embezzler and be surprised when they look up the records.

Answer (score 9):

Yes,

Page 116 of DtD states in the case where someone makes a Pact with a man to take his relationship with his girlfriend:

*When the deal is struck, the demon’s Cover absorbs that relationship – as far as the girlfriend is concerned, she’s been dating the demon all along. Obvious signs of their relationship are likewise altered, such as prominently displayed photos of the couple.*

There are "levels" of Pacts (beginning at DtD p.190).  I would say that the "greater" the Pact, the better the paper trail.